# Generating Function question, need help

Tags: contest-math

Let $$h_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dbinom{n}{k} \frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$
If $$S= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{h_{n}}{n!},$$
find $\lfloor S \rfloor $.

I calculated the first few values of n. I got,
when n=0, we get 2
when n=1, we get 4
when n=2, we get 26/3

i dont see a pattern

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference see also: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: Ok, that's good. Let's look at the first sum. Aside from the $k+1$ in the denominator, what does it remind you of?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: I got it thanks to @Dr.Mathva, thanks for the help Integrand

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Notice that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \left(3^{n+1}-1\right)$$ Eventhough some combinatorial argument might work in order to prove it, I think that the easiest is considering $\int_0^1 x^k dx = \frac{1}{k+1}$.

In order to finish the problem, simply recall that $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ I obtained $e^3-e\approx 17.37$

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to start:

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  = \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,n}   \cr 
  & \int_{x = 0}^t {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} dx} }  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{
  n \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right){{t^{\,k + 1} } \over {k + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{x = 0}^t {\left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,n} dx}
  = {1 \over {n + 1}}\left( {\left( {1 + t} \right)^{\,n + 1}  - 1} \right) \cr} 
$$

Comment: this is a fine hint but your bounds on the sum are tough to read

Comment: the bounds are indicated in brackets to underline that they can be omitted since they are implicit in the binomial